# How to change the sequences of the select statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a union of selects

```
     Select 'PM' as PM, @CountPM  as SumPM 
     Union
     Select 'CM' as CM, @CountCM as SumCM   
     Union 
     Select 'CMPM Ratio' as 'CM/PM Ratio', 0  as 'CMPMSUM'
     Union 
     select 'Bad Actors' as 'Bad Actors'
```

It comes like Bad Actors, CM, CMPM Ratio, PM but now I want to come it like the CM, PM, CMPM Ratio and then Bad Actors without moving the select statements from it's place.

Comment: You can't depend on any ordering that you don't explicitly add. Put a new column in there called `myorder` and give it a value of `1`,`2`,`3`, or `4`. Then wrap this thing in a subquery and use `ORDER BY myorder`

Comment: @JNevill: thanks but how?

Comment: Your last select statement has only one column, the query is invalid, you need to add a value after Bad Actors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `values()` and `order by`:

```
select v.col, v.value
from (values (1, 'PM', @CountPM),
             (2, 'CM', @CountCM), 
             (3, 'CMPM Ratio', 0),
             (4, 'Bad Actors', NULL)
    ) v(ind, col, value)
order by v.ind;
```

I am speculating on what you really want, because your `union` is malformed even without ordering.  The column names are taken from the first subquery -- and you have inconsistent column names in different subqueries.

Also, each subquery needs to have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment. Ordering in a table or even a query like this is pretty much random. You always have to explicitly tell it how to order. In your case, add a new column called `myorder` and then use that for ordering:

```
SELECT pm, sumpm
FROM
(
     Select 'PM' as PM, @CountPM  as SumPM,2 as myorder
     Union
     Select 'CM' as CM, @CountCM as SumCM, 1
     Union 
     Select 'CMPM Ratio' as 'CM/PM Ratio', 0  as 'CMPMSUM', 3
     Union 
     select 'Bad Actors' as 'Bad Actors', NULL, 4
) sub
ORDER BY myorder;
```

Ultimately, though, go with Gordon's answer since it solves your initial problem more elegantly.

Also, it's worth noting here that the column names to come out of your subquery are always based on the first SELECT in that list regardless of any other aliases you use.